# junit test cases not executing when spring boot application migrated from 2.1.5 to 2.4

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I had an application running in spring-boot 2.1.5, migrated that to version 2.4.0. None of my tests are executing now.
When I hit mvn clean test it always says 0 tests executed.

I noticed that spring boot 2.4.0 comes bundled with junit.jupiter library. My 2.1.5 tests are using junit:junit:4.4 dependency.

How to retain my old test cases without migrating to junit.jupiter?

Answer (score 2):

This is covered in the [release notes for Spring Boot 2.4](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.4-Release-Notes#junit-5s-vintage-engine-removed-from-spring-boot-starter-test):

> If you do not want to migrate your tests to JUnit 5 and wish to continue using JUnit 4, add a dependency on the Vintage Engine, as shown in the following example for Maven:
>
> ```xml
> <dependency>
>    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
>    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
>    <scope>test</scope>
>    <exclusions>
>        <exclusion>
>            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
>            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
>        </exclusion>
>    </exclusions>
> </dependency>
> ```
>
> If you are using Gradle, the equivalent configuration is shown in the following example:
>
> ```
> testImplementation("org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine") {
>    exclude group: "org.hamcrest", module: "hamcrest-core"
> }
> ```

Comment: I tried this, but annotations like "@ClassRule", "@Before", "@After" etc are not working

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Are they having no effect when your tests are being run, or at they causing compilation failures?

Comment: They're resulting into compilation failure

Comment: Those classes should come from `junit:junit` which is a transitive dependency of `junit-vintage-engine`. What does `mvn dependency:tree` or `./gradlew dependencies --configuration testCompileClasspath` show?